# How to register service as transient in Prism

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, prism, ioc-container

Recently I have used the Prism.DryIoC library into the WPF project. I discovered in App.xaml.cs class to override a RegisterTypes method

```
using Prism.Ioc;
using WpfAppNetCore.Views;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfAppNetCore
{
    public partial class App
    {
        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            // Register as Singleton 
            containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ITest, Test>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have an implementation of a class that inherits from the ITest interface as follows:

**ITest.cs**

```
namespace WpfAppNetCore
{
    public interface ITest
    {
        string GetTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
using System;

namespace WpfAppNetCore
{
    public class Test : ITest
    {
        #region Implementation of ITest

        public string GetTime { get; set; } = $"{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}";

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In a ViewModel I have called the GetTime property in ITest, and passed through the for loop.

```
public MainWindowViewModel(ITest test)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(test.GetTime);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Message = sb.ToString();
        }
```

If I register for ITest as a Singleton service, I will get the same result, which is true to my intention.

**But I don't know how to register ITest as a Transient Scope service to get different results after each iteration.**

Comment: it should read `public string GetTime => $"{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}";`

Comment: Yes! I had a mistake. Thank you for comment

Comment: So it doesn't matter at all whether (this) service is a singleton or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

```
 public string GetTime { get; set; } = $"{DateTime.Now:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}";
```

The above will only set the initial value of that property when the parent object is initialized.

In this example

```
public MainWindowViewModel(ITest test) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sb.AppendLine(test.GetTime);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    Message = sb.ToString();
}
```

The same initial value will be returned in the loop whether the injected dependency is singleton or transient.

According to source code repository, simply calling `Register`

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) {
    // Register as Transient
    containerRegistry.Register<ITest, Test>();
}
```

will register the mapped type as transient.

Answer (score 1):

For more information on how to register services you might want to check out the docs for [Prism](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/dependency-injection/index.html) and also the docs for the [Prism.Container.Extensions](https://prismplugins.com) which provide a number of more powerful options. You should NEVER ever be calling `GetContainer()` unless you have no other option. With the Container Extensions package you should NEVER have that need.